# (ODE Gain & Phase Lag) Does multiplying the numerator and denominator of the complex gain by 1 change its value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the gain and phase lag of x' + x = cos(t)? Does your answer change after multiplying the numerator and denominator of the complex gain by $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$? - Adapted from MIT OCW 18.03 Unit 2, Section Gain and Phase Lag.

With complex replacement, we would like the Real Component of a function z(t) such that $z' + z = e^{it}$. The characteristic equation of this LTI ODE is $p(r) = r + 1$ and assuming the answer $z(t)$ takes the form of $e^{it}$, we can solve for $z(t)$ by:

$z(t) = \frac{1}{p(i)}e^{it} = \frac{1}{i + 1}e^{it}$.

The complex gain is simply:

$\tilde{g}(t) = \frac{1}{1+i}$

Then we might say the gain of the system is:

$g(t) = \frac{1}{|p(i)|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Similarly, the phase lag is $tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{1}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Now, if we multiply the complex gain $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$, the complex gain becomes:

$\tilde{g}(t) = \frac{-1}{-1 - i}$

and the gain and phase lag can be computed as:

$g(t) = \frac{-1}{|-p(i)|} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$
with phase lag $\phi = tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{-1}) = \frac{-3\pi}{4}$ (using polar coordinates to recognize that a negative divided by a negative resides in Quadrant 3).

This result suggests that the gain and the phase lag of the solution can adopt two disparate values (which seems to be a contradiction). The caveat to the prior statement is if and only if shifting the solution by $-\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and inverting the amplitude is equivalent to shifting by $\frac{pi}{4}$. Plotting on wolfram alpha, this latter explanation seems true: cos(t - $\frac{\pi}{4}$) = -1*cos(t + $\frac{3\pi}{4}$).

Would someone offer some intuition or explanation on this example? Does it simply boil down as two equivalent ways of expressing the same function?